# Retrieve highest value from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can retrieve that data:

```
Name     Title      Profit
Peter    CEO        2
Robert   A.D        3
Michael  Vice       5
Peter    CEO        4
Robert   Admin      5
Robert   CEO        13
Adrin    Promotion  8
Michael  Vice       21
Peter    CEO        3
Robert   Admin      15
```

to get this:

```
Peter........4
Robert.......15
Michael......21
Adrin........8
```

I want to get the highest profit value from each name. 
If there are multiple equal names always take the highest value.

Comment: In the future, please don't stuff your sample data with meaningless `.......` - white space is actually a lot more useful.

Comment: @Aaron But then its not displayed like a table. I just meant it in a good way to help those who regard it. I changed the first part and removed the .... Do you like the result?

Comment: Yes, and that still looks like a table to me.

Comment: Yes it does because Martin Smith corrected it somehow.

Comment: I think he just added spaces instead of dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name,max(profit) from table group by name
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this type of request almost always follows with "now can I include the title?" - here is a query that gets the highest profit for each name but can include all the other columns without grouping or applying arbitrary aggregates to those other columns:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Name, Title, Profit, rn = ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Profit DESC)
  FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT Name, Title, Profit
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Actually you are right I have to include more fields. But then the solution of hkutluay does not work, but yours does. But I can not change the question or that would not be fair therefore I flagged hkutluay`s answer as solution. Gave you a point and thank you, the CTE with the Over clause is interesting to learn.